# DateTimeFormat.forPattern accepts illegal pattern

Tags: java, jodatime, datetime-format

`DateTimeFormat.forPattern("2007-05-24 00:00-06:00")` does not throw an exception. Is this the expected behavior?

In my logic, I would like to validate if a string is either a datetime format or actual datetime string. I was hoping for the above code to help me with it.

- JODA version is 2.9.5.
- JAVA version: 8 (update 151)

Comment: _Any characters in the pattern that are not in the ranges of ['a'..'z'] and ['A'..'Z'] will be treated as quoted text._

Comment: Are you getting formats dynamically? Why do you have to validate them?

Comment: Yes, I get them dynamically. And the code is not strongly typed to differentiate if it is a date string or a date format string.

Comment: That’s a valid pattern. There is no requirement that the pattern must contain format pattern letters (though it’s rather pointless not to, I agree with you).

Comment: There is no obvious and easy way to distinguish. If your string has letters and no digits, it’s a pattern; if it has digits and no letters, it’s date-time; but if it has both? Like `2007-05-24T00:00Z`. I think you should make a rule of thumb based on your real data.

Answer (score -2):

The `DateTimeFormat.forPattern()` returns a `DateTimeFormatter` object.
if you pass a wrong pattern as argument, it throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: Invalid pattern specification.
I suggest you validate the pattern with regex. [Check](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) examples of valid datetime patterns

Comment: If this answers the question, I have not understood how? And the link is clearly irrelevant.